# MYSQL DB keeps crashing (Ubuntu 14.04. / MySQL 5.6)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, innodb, mysql-5.6

I am having a hard time figuring out why my DB keeps crashing.

The last `status` is this:

```
 * /usr/bin/mysqladmin  Ver 8.42 Distrib 5.6.16, for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64
Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Server version      5.6.16-1~exp1
Protocol version    10
Connection      Localhost via UNIX socket
UNIX socket     /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:         21 hours 19 min 24 sec

Threads: 8  Questions: 1431709  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 799  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 117  Queries per second avg: 18.650
```

Here is the log, shortly before the crash:
[PASTEBIN](http://pastebin.com/YGg2Dtr3)

I know I have a lot of queries (I believe) for only ~22hours, but this is only internal usage, so no other load. 
I am running with 256MB, is that too low?

I read something about a "slow/mini" setup for MySQL, is that useful?

EDIT:

ran     mysqltuner and it gives me:
    Maximum possible memory usage: 352.4M (161% of installed RAM)

How can I reduce that?

Comment: Reduce `innodb_buffer_pool_size` value in your `my.cnf` (it tells you it can't allocate sufficient memory in the log). Also, do you have `file_per_table` turned on? You're running out of file descriptors. How many processes are hitting your MySQL anyway? Just one or more than one?

Comment: There is no such pool_size in my conf, should I just add it? Where can I see the processors? Also  don't know where to set file_per_table. I am a very beginner...

Comment: Yes, just add those to your `my.cnf` if they're not in the file already.

Comment: Does your system have swap space? If not, you might benefit from having  swap space of 1GB or so. Type `free -m`. If you have swap, it will show up in the last line of the output.

Answer (score 0):

256M is *tiny* by today's standards, but possible.

Make sure the performance_schema is turned off; it chews up memory in 5.6.  (5.7 is better.)

Tuner is pessimistic, so the 161% is not necessarily disaster.  However, it is computing only the *data* needed for MySQL, not room for the OS, MySQL code, or any applications.

So, yes, decrease various tunables.  Usually `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is the biggest and can be decreased down to, say, 30M.  Other possibilities:  `max_connections = 10`, `table_open_cache = 100`, `threads_cached = 3`.  Any of these changes may (or may not) cause performance to suffer.  But crashing is worse.

You should look into getting more RAM.  And/or move non-mysql apps off that server.

Do you have the error message when it crashes?  Look in `mysqld.err`.  The error may indicate which tunable it is having trouble with.